# Import Multiple .sql dump files into mysql database from shell

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I have a directory with a bunch of `.sql` files that mysql dumps of each database on my server.

e.g.

```
database1-2011-01-15.sql
database2-2011-01-15.sql
...
```

There are quite a lot of them actually.

I need to create a shell script or single line probably that will import each database.

I'm running on a Linux Debian machine.

I thinking there is some way to pipe in the results of a ls into some find command or something..

any help and education is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

So ultimately I want to automatically import one file at a time into the database.

E.g. if I did it manually on one it would be:

```
mysql -u root -ppassword < database1-2011-01-15.sql
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`cat *.sql | mysql`?  Do you need them in any specific order?

If you have too many to handle this way, then try something like:

```
find . -name '*.sql' | awk '{ print "source",$0 }' | mysql --batch
```

This also gets around some problems with passing script input through a pipeline though you shouldn't have any problems with pipeline processing under Linux.  The nice thing about this approach is that the `mysql` utility reads in each file instead of having it read from `stdin`.

Comment: In the end i used the cat \*.sql but broke it down by letter so there wasn't too much info. e.g. cat a\*.sql | mysql -u root -ppass

Comment: I used `ls -1 *.sql | awk '{ print "source",$0 }' | mysql --batch -u {username} -p{password} {dbname} ` as I have named my sql files sequentially and  wanted to execute in that order

Comment: @Luracast I used `ls -1 *.sql | awk '{ print "source",$0 }' | mysql --batch -u {username} -p {dbname}` to get it working. The password needs to be entered in the console when it actually prompts for it, not in the command itself. MySQL doesn't accept password in the command.

Comment: @satya I believe that you can enter the password on the command line if you use `--password=PA55w0rd` instead of `-p`.  I haven't tinkered with MySQL in quite some time, but I'm pretty sure that would work.

Comment: @D.Shawley and @satya - you can enter the password on the command line with -p you just omit the space. e.g. `mysql -u me -pPA55w0rd`

Comment: is --batch really necessary?

Comment: Or use pv for progress: `pv -p *.sql | mysql database `taken by: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/59139471/8398149](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59139471/8398149)

Answer (score 20):

One-liner to read in all `.sql` files and imports them:

```
for SQL in *.sql; do DB=${SQL/\.sql/}; echo importing $DB; mysql $DB < $SQL; done
```

The only trick is the bash substring replacement to strip out the `.sql` to get the database name.

Comment: Like a charm, thanks for this! Worked better than the accepted answer for me.

Answer (score 10):

There is superb little script at http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mydumpsplitter-extract-tables-from-mysql-dump-shell-script which will take a *huge* mysqldump file and split it into a single file for each table. Then you can run this very simple script to load the database from those files:

```
for i in *.sql
do
  echo "file=$i"
  mysql -u admin_privileged_user --password=whatever your_database_here < $i
done
```

mydumpsplitter even works on .gz files, but it is much, much slower than gunzipping first, then running it on the uncompressed file.

I say *huge*, but I guess everything is relative. It took about 6-8 minutes to split a 2000-table, 200MB dump file for me.

Answer (score 3):

I don't remember the syntax of mysqldump but it will be something like this

```
 find . -name '*.sql'|xargs mysql ...
```

Comment: from doing a bit of research that is what I'm coming up with too. e.g.  find . -name '*.sql' | xargs mysql -u root -ppassword    Would that work?

Comment: and -h host if you are on a remote server and probably also need to specify database name

Comment: the database is referenced in each backupfile so the single line above works already and it is the localhost

Answer (score 3):

I created a script some time ago to do precisely this, which I called (completely uncreatively) "myload". It loads SQL files into MySQL.

[Here it is on GitHub](https://github.com/tylerl/util/blob/master/mysql/myload)

It's simple and straight-forward; allows you to specify mysql connection parameters, and will decompress gzip'ed sql files on-the-fly. It assumes you have a file per database, and the base of the filename is the desired database name.

So:

```
myload foo.sql bar.sql.gz
```

Will create (if not exist) databases called "foo" and "bar", and import the sql file into each.

For the other side of the process, I wrote [this script (mydumpall)](https://github.com/tylerl/util/blob/master/mysql/mydumpall) which creates the corresponding sql (or sql.gz) files for each database (or some subset specified either by name or regex).