# Restoring SQL from multiple SQL files

Tags: mysql

I have a database backup with 400+ sql files. foreach table there is a separate sql file. Is it possible to import all this files together to a database? If so could you tell me how to do this?

Also the backup is a gzipped tar file. Is there a way to restore from a compressed file.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708013/import-multiple-sql-dump-files-into-mysql-database-from-shell

Comment: @Haim, thanks for pointing me the right post. I like the find method with awk script. It works perfectly. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the answer for my question here. [Import Multiple .sql dump files into mysql database from shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708013/import-multiple-sql-dump-files-into-mysql-database-from-shell)

`find . -name '*.sql' | awk '{ print "source",$0 }' | mysql --batch` works perfectly. Thanks for @Haim to pointing out the correct post.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using linux Concatenate all the sql files using and

```
cat *.sql > fullBackup.sql
```

then you can restore the database using this backup file

Answer (score 1):

Nowdays processors have many cores. To use all the cores:

```
for s in *.sql.gz ; do   gunzip -c  $s | mysql -u sql_user -p'password' database_name  &   done
```

This command opens background process for each sql-dump file.

Answer (score 0):

Or, with pv installed, you can see also the progress by using:

```
pv -p *.sql | mysql database
```