# Import folder of .sql files into a single database

Tags: mysql, import, command-line-interface

I want to import a number (over 100) .sql files into a single database. I can do this for one

```
mysql -u root -p db_name < /tmp/export/data.sql
```

But I have a lot, so I tried this but it fails stating "ambiguous redirect"

```
mysql -u root -p db_name < /tmp/export/*
```

Is there another approach I can use from the command line to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708013/import-multiple-sql-dump-files-into-mysql-database-from-shell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
find . -name '*.sql' | awk '{ print "source",$0 }' | mysql --batch -u root -p db_name
```

Answer (score 3):

I would try something like

```
cat * | mysql -u root -p db_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe trying

```
mysql -u root -p db_name < /tmp/export/*.sql
```

would be an effective alternative.

Comment: Same issue I am afraid

Answer (score 0):

First merge all your .sql files into one and then upload the merged file.

To merge multiple .sql files type in the directory with your .sql files:

```
`copy *.sql all.sql`
```

Then upload to your database:

```
mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD DATABASENAME < all.sql
```