# How do i import into mysql daily via cron or ssh

Tags: mysql, cron

I want to write a cron job to INSERT INTO 6 tables. I know that :

1. The tables will always exist and will be empty, awaiting records
2. I will have 6 .sql dump files On the server which will be ready to be imported.
3. The format of the files are exactly as created by the phpMyAdmin export tool
   i.e. all already have a single INSERT INTO `tablename` line and multiple parenthisised value lines.
4. All have foreign-key constraints set to off before the insert statement and toggled on again after the inserts.

i wanted to do all from within PHP but on a shared hosting the exec() func is disabled and so is the FILES priviledge so my options are dwindling.

I'm looking for a way to do the above from cPanel cron or SSH tools in cPanel. CRON would be my first choice since i'm unfamiliar with SSH.

**Do i run this line 6 times (for each file) or can i consolidate it into one cron or ssh command? p.s. also do i use absolute or relative paths to the .sql dump files**

```
mysql -h localhost -u myusername -p mypassword mycatalogdb < 'sqlcronfiles/dump-1.sql'
mysql -h localhost -u myusername -p mypassword mycatalogdb < 'sqlcronfiles/dump-2.sql'
mysql -h localhost -u myusername -p mypassword mycatalogdb < 'sqlcronfiles/dump-3.sql'
mysql -h ... etc ...
```

thanks

Comment: Wait....did you test the cron with just one file and it works right??

Comment: no, haven't done that since i'm not in doubt it will import one way or the other - im more concerned with how to do it with 6 files without locking up the server and creating massive overhead

Comment: Start from something simple and then move out to something bigger...try with one file and see if the cron get executed, and fill the database...when you have that process ok, error free, then go to one of those alternatives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708013/import-multiple-sql-dump-files-into-mysql-database-from-shell

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `task.sh` file located at /home/youruser/ and inside you can put the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -h localhost -u myusername -p mypassword mycatalogdb < 'sqlcronfiles/dump-1.sql'
mysql -h localhost -u myusername -p mypassword mycatalogdb < 'sqlcronfiles/dump-2.sql'
mysql -h localhost -u myusername -p mypassword mycatalogdb < 'sqlcronfiles/dump-3.sql'
mysql -h localhost -u myusername -p mypassword mycatalogdb < 'sqlcronfiles/dump-4.sql'
mysql -h localhost -u myusername -p mypassword mycatalogdb < 'sqlcronfiles/dump-5.sql'
mysql -h localhost -u myusername -p mypassword mycatalogdb < 'sqlcronfiles/dump-6.sql'
```

Then, to execute this cron, from cPanel, you create a Cronjob, configure the time as needed and the command it should execute is:

```
/home/youruser/task.sh
```

And you are done.
I hope it works for you